# How to convert delimited text to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Delimited Text File(filename is data) =>

```
01 - Rental Details Rental ID,01 - Rental Details Local Start Time,01 - Rental Details Local End Time,01 - Rental Details Bike ID,01 - Rental Details Duration In Seconds Uncapped,03 - Rental Start Station ID,03 - Rental Start Station Name,02 - Rental End Station ID,02 - Rental End Station Name,User Type,Member Gender,05 - Member Details Member Birthday Year
22178529,2019-04-01 00:02:22,2019-04-01 00:09:48,6251,446.0,81,Daley Center Plaza,56,Desplaines St & Kinzie St,,Male,1975
22178530,2019-04-01 00:03:02,2019-04-01 00:20:30,6226,"1,048.0",317,Wood St & Taylor St,59,Wabash Ave & Roosevelt Rd,Subscriber,Female,1984
```

Converted JSON File(filename is data.JSON)

```js
{
    "01 - Rental Details Rental ID": "22178529",
    "01 - Rental Details Local Start Time": "2019-04-01 00:02:22",
    "01 - Rental Details Local End Time": "2019-04-01 00:09:48",
    "01 - Rental Details Bike ID": "6251",
    "01 - Rental Details Duration In Seconds Uncapped": "446.0",
    "03 - Rental Start Station ID": "81",
    "03 - Rental Start Station Name": "Daley Center Plaza",
    "02 - Rental End Station ID": "56",
    "02 - Rental End Station Name": "Desplaines St & Kinzie St",
    "User Type": "Subscriber",
    "Member Gender": "Male",
    "05 - Member Details Member Birthday Year": "1975",
},
{
    "01 - Rental Details Rental ID": "22178529",
    "01 - Rental Details Local Start Time": "2019-04-01 00:02:22",
    "01 - Rental Details Local End Time": "2019-04-01 00:09:48",
    "01 - Rental Details Bike ID": "6251",
    "01 - Rental Details Duration In Seconds Uncapped": "446.0",
    "03 - Rental Start Station ID": "81",
    "03 - Rental Start Station Name": "Daley Center Plaza",
    "02 - Rental End Station ID": "56",
    "02 - Rental End Station Name": "Desplaines St & Kinzie St",
    "User Type": "Subscriber",
    "Member Gender": "Male",
    "05 - Member Details Member Birthday Year": "1975",
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delimited text to nested javascript object/JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673284/delimited-text-to-nested-javascript-object-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split rows on newline
match on quoted string, or normal string, or comma and no string (blank)
splice out header first row as keys

map rows to object map

```js
text = `01 - Rental Details Rental ID,01 - Rental Details Local Start Time,01 - Rental Details Local End Time,01 - Rental Details Bike ID,01 - Rental Details Duration In Seconds Uncapped,03 - Rental Start Station ID,03 - Rental Start Station Name,02 - Rental End Station ID,02 - Rental End Station Name,User Type,Member Gender,05 - Member Details Member Birthday Year
22178529,2019-04-01 00:02:22,2019-04-01 00:09:48,6251,446.0,81,Daley Center Plaza,56,Desplaines St & Kinzie St,,Male,1975
22178530,2019-04-01 00:03:02,2019-04-01 00:20:30,6226,"1,048.0",317,Wood St & Taylor St,59,Wabash Ave & Roosevelt Rd,Subscriber,Female,1984`


const rows = text.split(/\r?\n/g)
  .map(x => 
    [...x.matchAll(/(?:"([^"]+?)"|([^,]+?)|(,))(?=,|$)/g)]
      .map(([,quoted,x,])=>quoted||x||'')) //extract string or blank
const keys = rows.shift() //extract first row of keys

console.log(
rows.map(row=>Object.fromEntries(
  row.map((v,i)=>[keys[i],v])
))
)
```

Comment: can you please slice date like "01 - Rental Details Local End Time": "2019-04-01", in all objects

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple CSV format probably this would help:

```js
function convert(csv) {
  const result = {};
  const lines = csv.split('\n').map(line => line.split(','));

  for (let i = 0; i < lines[0].length; i++) {
    result[lines[0][i]] = lines[1][i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

PS. Assuming there are exact 2 lines (header & values), values inside each line are comma-separated.

Comment: I see there are more than 2 lines for values and you need to get a list. I believe the code above is easily extendable for it.

Comment: Yes Converted JSON we want in LIST